# Submitting User Data in Javascript MVC Frameworks

Tags: javascript, flask, sammy.js

This is my first attempt at making a webapp using a JavaScript MVC  framework and I need some pointers about what are the right ways in getting the following accomplished.

I'm making a voting application in Flask (server-side) and Sammy.js on the client. I've implemented the routes and views perfectly but I'm confused as to how send back data to the server since the "form" in my case is split across different views. [Here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nctfT.png). You can see that the candidates standing for each post are displayed at `http://127.0.0.1:5000/#/post_id` where I'm fetching data in json and rendering it using the sammy's templates.

My question is about storing users votes. Each tile in the screenshot will have a radio button and the I want to somehow get all the users votes(across all the posts) and send them as a query string(I'm not sure if this is correct) to the server to record the votes.

Is there a certain way to address such problems in front-end development? I'm totally clueless to this pattern of development as I've only developed the more traditional (server-side heavy) applications. Any pointers would be appreciated. Thanks a bunch!

PS: Apologies for the misleading title. I was finding it too hard to find something more descriptive.